# putParcelableArrayListExtra and black screen

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have custom class that implements `Parcelable` and I use it as custom arraylist.

When I use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` and 400 rows it works fine, but 1000 rows it does not. I have black screen and app locks up. What is wrong?

EDIT:
I sent it here and I don't use it in another Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), ArtActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra ("mylist", list);
startActivityForResult(intent, SECONDARY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

My array:

```
ArrayList<Piece> list = new ArrayList<Piece>();
```

It is my Class:

```
public class Piece implements Parcelable { 
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int type;
    private String text;
    private String mp3;

   public Piece (String id,String name,int type)
   {
     this.id=id;
     this.name=name;
     this.type=type;
   }

   public Piece(Piece ele)
   {
      this.id=ele.id;
      this.name=ele.name;
      this.type=ele.type;
      this.text=ele.text;
   }

   public Piece (Parcel in) 
   { 
        id = in.readString (); 
        name = in.readString (); 
        type = in.readInt();
        text= in.readString();
        mp3=in.readString();
   } 

   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Piece> CREATOR 
   = new Parcelable.Creator<Piece>()  
  { 
        public Piece createFromParcel(Parcel in)  
        { 
            return new Piece(in); 
        } 

        public Piece[] newArray (int size)  
        { 
            return new Piece[size]; 
        } 
   }; 


   public void makeText(String text)
   {
       this.text=text;
   }



   public void makeMp3(String mp3)
   {
     this.mp3= mp3;
   }

   public String getMp3()
   {
   return this.mp3;
   }

   public String getId()
   {
       return id;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   }
   public int getType()
   {
       return type;
   }
   public String getText()
   {
       return text;
   }

  public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString (id); 
    dest.writeString (name);
    dest.writeInt(type);
    dest.writeString (text); 
    dest.writeString (mp3);
  } 
}
```

Comment: May I ask what you are using the parcelable for? I may have a solution for you depending on what you're using the data for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you should be using parcelable in this case. I would either access the data statically (if you only intend to have one persistent instance of the data), or use a caching system to hold onto the data.

This is an example of a publicly available static variable:

```
public static List<Piece> list;
```

It is accessible from everywhere in your app that has visibility of the class.

However, doing this is very messy and is considered a bad practice. Alternatively, you can create an object to manage the data for you as a static class or singleton:

```
public class MyListManager {
    private static List<Piece> mList;

    public static List<Piece> getMyList() {
        return mList;
    }

    public static void setList(List<Piece> list) {
        mList = list;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement some kind of a caching system to manage your data.